IAudioSessionControl *pSessionControl->QueryInterface(IID_IAudioSessionControl2, IAudioSessionControl2 **) return a unknown big integer. Why
HRESULT ASCtl_Impl::__GetProcessName(
    IAudioSessionControl *const pSessionControl, std::wstring &processName)
{
    if (pSessionControl == nullptr) {
        return E_POINTER;
    }

    IAudioSessionControl2 *pSessionControl2 = nullptr;
    DWORD processId = 0;
    HRESULT hr = pSessionControl->QueryInterface(
        IID_IAudioSessionControl2, reinterpret_cast<void **>(&pSessionControl2));
    if (SUCCEEDED(hr)) {
        hr = pSessionControl2->GetProcessId(&processId);
        pSessionControl2->Release(); 
    }

    if (SUCCEEDED(hr)) {

        TCHAR szProcessName[MAX_PATH];
        DWORD dwSize = ARRAYSIZE(szProcessName);

        HANDLE hProcess = OpenProcess(PROCESS_QUERY_LIMITED_INFORMATION, FALSE, processId);
        if (hProcess) {
            if (QueryFullProcessImageName(hProcess, 0, szProcessName, &dwSize)) {
                processName = szProcessName; 
            }
            CloseHandle(hProcess);
        }
    }

    return hr;
}

This is my code, i utilized this interface to grab process name.
but i met a abnormal return like below(i tried to echo the hr and the processName):

###GetDisplayName(szSessionName), return=143196173    szSessionName=###

what is normal return:

###GetDisplayName(szSessionName), return=0    szSessionName=C:\Program Files\DAUM\PotPlayer\PotPlayerMini64.exe###

my echo statements are here:

hr = __GetProcessName(pControl, szSessionName);
std::wcout << L"\t###GetDisplayName(szSessionName), return=" << hr
        << L"\tszSessionName=" << szSessionName << L"###" << std::endl;

my question is:
why the processName is blank and the hr is 0x889000d
cannt find the reason
any response is appreciated
my question is:
why the processName is blank and the hr is 0x889000d
cannt find the reason
any response is appreciated
